# Gnuplot: plotting results from different sources in one graph

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to compare the results of a measurement from different collaborations using gnuplot. The plot should ideally look like this:

[image: Example graph]

I can't figure out how to plot the different results one on top of the other, with the labels on the right. I would be really grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: I assume you have 3 different data files? How does the data look like? Just one data point? Please give an example of how the input data is structured.

Comment: Yes it's just a single data point (the value of \alpha) with associated errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I show two approaches, depending of your data file. Two possible structures are `data01.dat`

```
# data01.dat
alpha  error
 1.0    0.2
 2.0    0.2
 1.5    0.2
```

or `data02.dat`

```
# data02.dat
Collab alpha error
   1    1.0   0.2
   2    2.0   0.2
   3    1.5   0.2
```

Using the `data01-structure`:

```
reset
set encoding utf8
set terminal wxt size 480,600 font "Times New Roman,10"
set tics out nomirror
set xlabel "{/:Italic=12 α}"
set link y2
unset ytics
set y2range [:] reverse
set y2tics 1
set format y2 "Collaboration %g"
set offsets graph 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5

plot "data01.dat" u 1:0:2 w xerrorbars pt 7 not
```

Using the `data02-structure` almost all is the same, except the `plot` command.

```
plot "data02.dat" u 2:1:3 w xerrorbars pt 7 not
```

The results.

[image: Graph]

I hope be useful.